# How to apend the csv file after each iteration in C

Tags: c, csv, iteration

I am writing certain set of variables in CSV file after 10000 iteration. I want to write the file for intermediate iterations say after every 1000 iterations. How can I write the CSV file in C.

```
no_of_iteration=1000;
for ( n=0;n<no_of_iteration;n++){
//Perform operation on HorVel,VerVel,Pressure
}

fpCellAvgVal = fopen("cellAvgValue.csv", "w"); // Change to match your path

for(n = 1; n < jMax; n++){
    for(m = 1; m < iMax; m++)
        fprintf(fpCellAvgVal, "%lf,%lf ,%lf \n", Pressure[m][n], HorVel[m][n],VerVel[m][n]);
}

fclose(fpCellAvgVal);
```

How to write the data after every 1000 iterations in the same file?

Comment: Store the results in a char buffer first, then after 1000 iterations write the entire buffer to the CSV file.

Comment: Perhaps `fopen("cellAvgValue.csv", "a")` is what you're looking for. The `"a"` means *append*.

Comment: [this](http://codingstreet.com/create-csv-file-in-c/#) might help. And also answer of Jon Watte on [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6a12570b-df26-4736-9f32-60c8b0ccc281/how-to-write-into-a-csv-file-in-c?forum=vcgeneral).

Comment: @user3386109 seems to have pinpointed it. But if u r still in search of some solid reference then docs of `fopen` will help a lot. You can find good doc on [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yeby3zcb.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) with examples. Or on [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html). Or on [gnu page](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Opening-Streams.html)